# Proxy to connect to XML cross server..Using Ajax works on some browsers not others? code included

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax, xml-parsing

Ok so first let me explain what I am doing:

I am trying to connect to http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml to grab the xml and parse it of course cross domain policy wont allow me to do this directly. SOOOO..

I am using PHP to connect to the site through a proxy and this works perfectly

Then back in my main HTML file I am using Ajax to parse through that XML file. Problem is I am getting mixed results. For instance on my macbook pro with all the latest browsers (Safari, Firefox, Chrome) this doesn't work. On my iPhone it works. and on my Mac Desktop with all latest browsers it works.

Anyone know why?

ALSO I have no clue what I am doing with XML this is my very first attempt to learn how to read through XML. SO I may need you to explain how to better parse though as the way I am doing it now is from a fellow online user.

Here is the PHP proxy which works:

```
<?php

$server_url = "http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml";

$options = array
(
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET        => 1
);

$service = $_GET["service"];

$request_headers = Array();
foreach($_SERVER as $i=>$val) {
        if (strpos($i, 'HTTP_') === 0) {
                $name = str_replace(array('HTTP_', '_'), array('', '-'), $i);
                if ($name != 'HOST')
                {
                    $request_headers[] = "{$name}: {$val}";
                }
        }
}

$options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $request_headers;

switch (strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]))
{

    case "post":
        $options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
        $url = "{$server_url}".$service;

        $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = file_get_contents("php://input");

        break;
    case "get":

        unset($_GET["service"]);

        $querystring = "";
        $first = true;
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $val)
        {
            if (!$first) $querystring .= "&";
            $querystring .= $key."=".$val;
            $first = false;
        }

        $url = "{$server_url}".$service."?".$querystring;

        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unsupported request method.");
        break;

}

$options[CURLOPT_URL] = $url;

$curl_handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl_handle,$options);
$server_output = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$response = explode("\r\n\r\n",$server_output);
$headers = explode("\r\n",$response[0]);

foreach ($headers as $header)
{
    if ( !preg_match(';^transfer-encoding:;ui', Trim($header))  )
    {
        header($header);
    }
}

echo $response[1]; 


?> 

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the troublesome HTML file with AJAX:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.allencoded.com/test3.php",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        // Interpret response
        $(xml).find('g').each(function() {

            // Example: Show the XML tag in the console
            console.log(this);

            // Example: Put some output in the DOM
            $("#divOutput").append($(this).attr("hnn"));

        });

        $(xml).find('g').each(function() {



            // Example: Put some output in the DOM
            $("#divOutput").append($(this).attr("vnn"));

        });        

    }
});
</script>

<div id="divOutput"></div>

</body></html>
```

Finally here is XML for reference:
http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml

I am really looking for a way to parse this as it will be an awesome learning experience. BTW if it helps Firefox on my macbook with all the problems is telling me: missing ) in parenthetical line 12

Also I would greatly appreciate it if you were so kind to answer in terms a noobie may understand for dealing with XML as I am new to it.

Thanks!

Edit:
Adding my website links to this code:
http://allencoded.com/footballxml.html
and 
http://allencoded.com/test3.php

Comment: I tested the HTML with the jQuery code locally - works fine, in Chromium and Firefox on Linux. The error you get could really be a missing ) - did you check that there is really no typo on the machine where it is not working?

Comment: same code on both machines as it is used from a website. I really am stumped with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not caused by some C&P issue, this could be the cause:

```
$(xml).find('g').each(function() {



        // Example: Put some output in the DOM
        $("#divOutput").append($(this).attr("vnn"));

}) //Here is a colon missing!
```

Comment: added the colon still not working on the macbook pro which is brand new but works on everything else still

Comment: Ha I just cleared the cache for Safari and magically it works in all my browsers again go figure...BTW running Mac OSX Lion if anyone has the same issue ever

Comment: Thanks for accepting though it was not really the solution. I hope I still could help a bit...